# Not showing the Price correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have products with prices in USD on my db.

And also i have different currencies.

USD = 1,000000
EURO = 0,807101

The price that i have for the product is 150.50 but showing allways as150.00. I do not know the reason.

```
<span><?php echo get_tour_currency_price($tour_data[0]->tour_lowest_price,"sup");?></span>
```

And when i change the currency it gives 121.00 Euro. Must be 121.46 euros.

Here is the code i use to get the the price of the product by checking currecy rate.
 What can be the solutions to show correctly the price and converted rate?

```
    <?php
if (! defined ( 'BASEPATH' ))
    exit ( 'No direct script access allowed' );
function get_tour_currency_price($tour_price,$sup_html="") {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $currency_text = "$";
    $currency_rate = 1;

    if ($ci->session->userdata ( 'currency_rate' )) {
       $currency_text = $ci->session->userdata ( 'currency_display_text' );
       $currency_rate = $ci->session->userdata ( 'currency_rate' );
    }
    if($sup_html){
        return "<sup>".$currency_text."</sup> ". number_format( floor($tour_price * $currency_rate),2, '.', '');
    }
    else{
        return $currency_text. number_format( floor($tour_price * $currency_rate),2, '.', '');
    }
}   
function get_tour_numeric_currency_price($tour_price,$sup_html="") {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $currency_text = "$";
    $currency_rate = 1;

    if ($ci->session->userdata ( 'currency_rate' )) {
       $currency_text = $ci->session->userdata ( 'currency_display_text' );
       $currency_rate = $ci->session->userdata ( 'currency_rate' );
    }
    if($sup_html){
        return "<sup>".$currency_text."</sup>". floor ( ($tour_price * $currency_rate), 2, '.', '' );
    }
    else{
        return $currency_text. floor ( ($tour_price * $currency_rate), 2, '.', '' );
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP floor (http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) does not take other arguments.  So it is doing exactly what it should, it removes the decimal part.  You should be using round (http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP floor (php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) does not take other arguments. So it is doing exactly what it should, it removes the decimal part. You should be using round (php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: When i use round 150.50 comes as 151.00 Usd. BUt i want to show exactly 150.50 USd.

Comment: Round your number to 2 decimal ponts.  150.50237528978243 then becomes 150.50.  That is where the second argument == 2 comes in to play.  Check php.net/manual/en/function.round.php, there is an example of this.

Comment: Main price is in USD 150.50. And i wan toshow as it is.150.50. ANd when i convert to euro 121.468. And this must be 121.46 or 121,47

Comment: Ok so remove the floor function from your code, and no use for the round either.

Comment: Removed but this time. I got. numbers like €121.65468. So will need again to show 121.65.

Comment: So put the round() back, with 2 digits of precision.  Read the round documentation page!